# react-materialize Modal component stops working after a state update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, materialize

The Modal component from react-materialize stops working after a state update.

Here's my dependencies from my package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "materialize-css": "^1.0.0",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-materialize": "^3.8.3",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1"
  }
```

And a code snippet to reproduce the problem

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import 'materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.min.css'
import 'materialize-css'
import {Button, Modal} from 'react-materialize'

function App() {

  const [text, setText] = useState('INITIAL')

  function changeText(){
    setText('AFTER')
  }

  return (    
    <div className="App">
    <p>{text}</p>
    <Button onClick={changeText}>CLICK ME</Button>
     <Modal
      header='Modal Header'
      trigger={<Button>MODAL</Button>}>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
  </Modal>      
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

After refreshing the page if I click in MODAL button, the modal is displayed, but if I click first on CLICK ME button an then click on MODAL nothing is displayed.

Does anyone know a way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

It was a bug. Fixed on #1103 pull request:
https://github.com/react-materialize/react-materialize/pull/1103